# Java Post Method with Attachment JAX-RS from Bean

Tags: web-services, post, javabeans, attachment

I have an Email Web Service - working ok - and now I need to add attachment.

1.How do I write the @FormParam in my post method to receive byte[] ?

2.How do I write my bean the addParam to add the file?

My bean is like this:

```
public String sendEmail() throws IOException{            
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String ip = req.getRemoteAddr();

    String conteudo = "é ô ç $ & / { [";     
    List<byte[]> att = new ArrayList<byte[]>();        

    String request = "myURI";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(request); 
    method.getParams().setContentCharset("utf-8");       

    method.addParameter("conteudo", conteudo);
    method.addParameter("ip", ip);

    return "sendEmail ok";
}
```

My POST Method is like this:

```
@POST   
@Path("/sendEmail")
@Consumes({"application/json","application/x-www-form-urlencoded",})    
public String sEmail(@FormParam("conteudo") String conteudo, @FormParam("ip") String ip)throws MessagingException {

    String de = "de@mail.com.br";
    String para = "para@rmail.com.br";
    String cc = "";
    String cco = "";
    String titulo = "Email test";
    String conteudo = "conteudo";


    try {

        Email email = new SimpleEmail(); 
        email.setHostName("smtp....");
        email.setSmtpPort(25);
        email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
        email.setFrom(de); 
        email.addTo(para); 
        email.setSubject(titulo); 
        email.setMsg(conteudo); 

        if (!cc.equals("")){
            email.addCc(cc); 
        }
        if (!cco.equals("")){
            email.addBcc(cco); 
        }

        email.send();

    } catch (EmailException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e.getMessage());            
 }
```

I use JavaMail 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encoded to base64, then I put all the files into a String separated with **;**

In the web service first I split the String and then I decoded from base64.